# CouldNotLoadArgumentException is thrown in JWS client

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to start a JWS application:

- It throws **`CouldNotLoadArgumentException` in Windows 8**.
- But if I try the same thing in other computer running Windows 7 it works just fine.

I have found couple of similar post in stack overflow and applied those suggestion:

1. Removed all property fields from JNLP file.
2. Cleared the temp files and browser cache.

But still it failed.

### Stack trace

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Unable to load the specified file/URL: C:\Users\N -~1\AppData\Local\Temp\javaws5]
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[27-07-2015 23:55:30] Esther.Hung : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\N -~1\AppData\Local\Temp\javaws5 (System can not find the path specified.)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: First of all Its a great software. My point is with the same jar it works in the other environment, in only one computer it throws this error.

Comment: *"My point is with the same jar it works in the other environment,.."*  Once a JNLP file is invalid, it is anyone's guess how a JWS client will parse it.  It might change from one (micro-)version to the next of the same manufacturer's JRE.  *"First of all Its a great software."*  Thanks!  But did it report any red colored errors in the JNLP?

Comment: there are few red colored (all are same errors though) cvc-complex-type2.4a: Invalid content was found starting with element description. One of {vendor} is expected.

Comment: That error means that JNLP elements are out of the correct order.  Consult the [Structure of the JNLP File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html) & put the elements in the same order as it does.